# How to get a value, using python, from a selected option in a drop down list in HTML? (FLASK)

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following code for my form in HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="feedback">
    <p><h2>Give us your feedback on the cafe!</h2>
        <h4><em>Maximum of 150 Characters.</em></h4>
    </p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('feedback') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="fb">Feedback</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="fb" placeholder="Enter your Feedback here..." type="text" maxlength="150"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="rating">Rating for Cafe</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="rating">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option selected>3</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="postal_code" placeholder="Postal Code of Cafe" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried to use rating = request.form.get("rating") in my python code to obtain the value of "rating" from the form, however I was unable to get the value in rating at all. How can I get the selected value from the HTML form in python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select element needs a `name` attribute. As does your textarea.